# How to create your own advert engine for an Android App?

Tags: android, ads

I have an Android App and I would like to start putting non-intrusive advert into the app. However, I have the benefit of knowing exactly what products I would like to put in these adverts (which will basically be amazon "similar products" type things and a few other suppliers). Is there any ad-engine out there that will allow me to do this? The ones I see already just put what *they* think are suitable.

I have scoured and I can't find an example of this... Any ideas? Should I just bite the bullet and write my own classes to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh - I always seem to be answering my own questions- I don't do that deliberately but I figured if anybody else has the same Q then I might as well put it here.... Anyway, I've found an open source library called "AdWhirl" ( www.adwhirl.com ) which enables you to plug in your own adserver etc etc. I will be using / adapting this for my purposes... (or at least trying to).